# Azure Databricks: specify programmatically notebook path that contains special character '$' in dbutils.notebook.run

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a databricks notebook with the following line:

```
dbutils.notebook.run(f"{notebooks_base_path}/test_notebook", 60, {})
```

The value string for "notebooks_base_path" parameter is an existing root path in the workspace with this value: "/base/oracle/dim/ops$test"

When execute it, recieve an exception related to parsing the notebook path:

**com.databricks.WorkflowException: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED: Notebook not found: /base/oracle/dim/ops$test/test_notebook**

I suppose there is an issue parsing "$" in the path, any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we can handle it in different approach as python variables as like this ,

```
var_1 = 'Users'
var_2 = 'id@heb.com'
var_3 = 'pull'
var_2 = 'r183532@heb.com'
var = '/'+ var_1 + '/' + var_2 +'/'+ var_3
print(var)
dbutils.notebook.run(var,10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible to do right now because of the some internal implementation details. Escaping of the `$` character with `\` and `$` doesn't help.

I recommend to open a support ticket to solve it.

P.S. Also, you may look onto [multitask jobs](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/jobs/index.html) instead, and or [arbitrary files in Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules) (if your code is in Python)